# Can't get my main nav to perform as a sticky nav

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

I've created a utility and main navigation bar for this self-project I'm working on, and I want the main nav to become sticky when I scroll 42px.

However, when I scroll the navigation bar doesn't stick at the top of the window. I tested it with the utility nav, and it worked perfectly. Here is my coding for the main nav bar...

```js
$(window).on("scroll", function () {

 var distanceScrolled = $(window).scrollTop();

 console.log("The distance scrolled is: " + distanceScrolled);

 if(distanceScrolled>42){
  $("#main-nav").addClass("scrolled");
 }

 else{
  $("#main-nav").removeClass("scrolled");
 }
});
```

```css
#main-nav {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: #000000;
}

.main-nav-left {
 list-style: none;
 float: left;
 padding-left: 28px;
 height: 100px;
}

.main-nav-items {
 position: absolute;
 top: 40%;
 left: 290px;
 list-style: none;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.main-nav-items li {
 display: inline-block;
 padding-right: 12px;
 margin-right: 13px;
}

.main-nav-right li {
 float: right;
 padding-right: 12px;
 margin-right: 26px;
 margin-top: 40px;
 list-style: none;
}

#main-nav a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #ffffff;
}

.scrolled {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<nav id="main-nav">
  <ul class="main-nav-left">
      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thule_logo.png" height="100" width="auto"></a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="main-nav-items">
   <li><a href="#">CARRIERS & RACKS</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">ACTIVE WITH KIDS</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">LUGGAGE & BAGS</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">SLEEVES & CASES</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">EXPLORE THULE</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="main-nav-right">
   <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-search fa-lg"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<script src="js/jquery-v3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: You haven't added jQuery to your snippet, which from the syntax - and the error in the console: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` - seems to be a requirement.

Comment: To add jQuery to your HTML file, within the head section, add: `<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>`

Comment: Have you considered just using [`position: sticky`](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/m9v7f85d/) (docs: [W3C](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-position-3/#position-property), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position))?

Comment: I forgot to add the script tags to the snippet. I have two script tags in my HTML: <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-v3.3.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>

Comment: I added a div around the "main-nav" tag and called on it in JS. It works, but the nav bar changes.

Answer (score 1):

First of all there is no 'nav' class defined for your html nav element. So in jQuery selector, you need to select by the id(main-nav) as you have defined or by HTML nav element itself. you can do this:

```
if(distanceScrolled>42){
        $("nav").addClass("scrolled");
    }

    else{
        $("nav").removeClass("scrolled");
}
```

or

```
if(distanceScrolled>42){
            $("#main-nav").addClass("scrolled");
        }

        else{
            $("#main-nav").removeClass("scrolled");
    }
```

But add jQuery library file prior to your custom script.

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

second and the most important thing is that you are adding a class(scrolled) having {position:fixed}. Since Id has higher priority than Class so it won't allow class to overwrite the common CSS property, like in this case 'position'. So you can add !important to class selector's property:

```
.scrolled{
    position:fixed!important;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    }
```

or

write deep CSS selection to make it's priority higher than Id. Like:

```
#main-nav.scrolled {
    position:fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Both will work.